# NetBeans formatting settings file

Tags: netbeans, formatting, editor, settings

Where does NetBeans store code formatting settings? I'd like to export them to another computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In Mac

Go to the main menu:

Netbeans, Preferences

- In Windows

Go to the main nemu:

Window, Options

- Then, in any of both

You will have to select any of the available tabs (editor, fonts and colors, ...) then click in export button

Once you have got the zip file, you can import it into another Netbeans's installation

Comment: Thanks! I had no clue about the export button.

Comment: Any idea where are the settings physically stored? I mean where could someone find the setting in netbeans installation dir.

Comment: In 8.0.2, this does not appear to export any formatting settings at all, besides the superficial indentation options.

Comment: @HugoZink you're right, it doesn't.  I'm also looking to export C++ formatting settings but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that this is an old post but since it's the top result when you google "netbeans php export formatting" and it came up in the comments of the approved answer:

Each module (and therefore each language) has to support the export. AFAIK Java had the support for years ( https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=143494 ) but other languages are still missing it (as for Netbeans 8.2).

I submitted a patch for PHP today which will hopefully be added: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=269978

If your langauge is missing in the export dialog, your langauge module does not yet support it. So head over to Netbeans and request it as feature or submit a patch.

Cheers
Bastian