# Change IntelliJ Scala syntax highlighting to Netbeans Scala syntax highlighting

Tags: netbeans, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

Is there are way to import the Netbeans color scheme of Scala syntax highlighting in to IntelliJ?

I just switched from Netbeans to IntelliJ and I am happy with it, Scala support seems to be much more finished. The only thing I am missing is the Netbeans scala syntax code highlighting. The IntelliJ default scala syntax highlighting is a bit basic compared to Netbeans.

Just asking before I start to recreate the syntax highlighting manually in the Color and Fonts setting.

Comment: Visit the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15266578/2650174) on similar question.

Comment: That is the export method in Netbeans. There is no import syntax highlighting (netbeans format) in IntelliJ.

Comment: Ok. Maybe you like [another color scheme](http://ideacolorthemes.org/) or you may find similar from NetBeans.